# Google Analytics - goal funnel max steps includes destination?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking, goals

I'm pretty new to GA and am having an issue. Two goals are being completed, when I am expecting only one.

I have two Goals set up, the only difference between them is that GoalA has an extra page, set to Step1 (Required = YES).
GoalA has five steps, plus a Destination. GoalB has four steps, plus a Destination.

When I go to the pages in GoalB, GoalA is also being recorded as being completed. But it should not, because I have not been to the page for Step1.

I read there is a maximum of five steps. Is my Destination being included as a sixth step and therefore Step1 is being ignored?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a real limit to the number of steps. You can continue to add steps. Can you include screenshots for your goals?

Comment: Can you screen shot the setup?

Comment: So GoalB is a subset of GoalA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple. Goal is triggered by its condition (in your case, destination url) and is not affected by funnel steps. So in terms of conversion reports goals with same destination but different funnel steps are equal. Funnel steps are only used for funnel visualization report.